# Merge overwrites a file that i've marked as assume no changes

Tags: git

I have an app.config file that I've marked as --assume no changes.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

All is fine.

But every time I merge the develop (main working branch that we all create Pull Requests into) into my branch, it overwrites that file.

I would expect this to happen if there were changes to the file.  But since the initial commit, there haven't been any.

There can (rarely) be changes to the file, so I don't want to add it to .gitignore.

I found one way via creating a "merge driver."  Seen [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b).

I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Comment: Are you sure that the `assume-unchanged` file exactly matches the file on the branch? Can you `diff` them?

Comment: @Nizar - the file on develop and the file on my branch (prior to merging) do not match.  The problem is they then match after the merge.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that they would not match, because you `assume-unchanged` it, so you probably did some changes to it then. But before you did any changes to it, it should match the stored file. Therefore, if you `git diff` the branches, the file shouldn't be listed. But if it is then I guess, you need to `no-assume-changed` then make them match again, `assume-unchanged`, then change the file again. Sorry if this doesn't help, but I am trying to relate your case to mine.

Comment: I would expect --assume-unchange to work when you want to do index operations (add, diff, status)... then it assumes the file is unchanged.... but when you are merging, that's not an index-related operation. But that's just my guess as to why this is happening.

Comment: @Nizar - that worked!  In summary, you need to mark --assume unchanged BEFORE you make changes to the file

Comment: Alright, I'll try to post it as an answer, I would appreciate an upvote :D

Comment: Yes, the `assume-unchanged` kind of makes any changes from the point you do it as if they weren't done. So if you change it before you `assume-unchanged` it, then it was already changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you marked it as unchanged before you make any changes.

The file before you `update-index` it as `--assume-unchanged` you want it to match the file that exists in the branch you want it to be "equal" with.

Therefore, try

1. `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file`
2. Change it back so it matches the file on the branch
3. `git update-index --assume-unchanged file`
4. Change it to your liking